# How can I label two equations within the same align environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, align

How can I references equations that are on the same line? Here is an example:

```
    \begin{align}
     & a_{11} = b_{11}, & a_{12} = b_{12}, \label{eq1}
     \\
     & a_{21} = b_{21}, & a_{22} = b_{22}, \label{eq2}
    \end{align}
```

If I have understood correctly, I can only reference the first or second line for this case. But I want to be able to reference each equation using `\eqref`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.